# msgfmt returns the wrong line with an error

Tags: gnu, gettext, po, msgfmt

today I'm having a problem. 
I deliberately created a `.po` file in which there is an error. 
I expect that the backtrace error appears on the **39** string. 
Instead, the validator shows

`test.po:1: missing 'msgstr' section` - means that validator found error on first line

Attaching a file

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: en_EN\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.3\n"

msgid "About"
msgstr "About"

msgid "Team"
msgstr "Team"

msgid "ICO"
msgstr "ICO"

msgid "Partners"
msgstr "Partners"

msgid "Blog"
msgstr "Blog"

msgid "contacts"
msgstr "contacts"

msgid "Subscribe"
msgid "Subscribe" // << Here must be an error
```

Please,help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in carriage return `^M`. I converted that carriage return to `\n` and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old for now, but if there is someone out there like me who got redirected to this question here's the problem:

Investigate the last line a bit further then you'll see that there stands `msgid` instead of `msgstr`.

So change from:

```
msgid "Subscribe"
msgid "Subscribe" // << Here must be an error
```

To this one:

```
msgid "Subscribe"
msgstr "Subscribe" // << Here was the error
```

One thing to mention: 
Another problem which could occur is that the `"` get wrong converted when you are copying your message strings from documents (e.g. Pages, Word, etc.). So keep that in mind.